# System.IO.Directory.Move(tempPath, newFolder) throws exception access denied

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-mvc-3, rights

I am trying to move a folder from one directory to another using this

```
System.IO.Directory.Move(tempPath, newFolder);
```

I am Administrator on my computer, so I should have full access. I cannot figure out why I get this exception once every two trying.

`Access to the path 'D:\<myDirectory>' is denied.`

Comment: Perhaps there is an open file in the temp-folder?

Comment: Since the question is tagged with asp.net-mvc-3, are you trying to do this from an asp.net application? If so, does the account under which the hosting process is executing have rights to both these locations?

Also, administrators can still be denied directory & file access through the security configuration of said file system elements.

Comment: @Hugo : I am doing this from an ASP MVC 3 application. And these two locations are inside another folder on which I have full control

Comment: Not sure about this, but worth trying. Have you tried running your VS as administrator? I've run into this beofre.

Comment: @RahulNomiddlenameRumalla: Nope still not working

Comment: Are you using any StreamReaders/Writers that might not have been disposed of before trying to move the directory?

Comment: @lboshuizen was right, There was an open file in the temp-folder but I coudn't find why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you're admin doesn't mean you can access everything. Among the things you can't necessarily access:

- Files/directories owned by SYSTEM which don't explicitly allow admins (e.g. C:\System Volume Information)
- Files locked by other processes with "share" settings which preclude your access

Comment: I checked the access rights of the directory in which I am doing this operation and I do have full control on it. Besides, as I said this works once and when I retry another time it gives this exception